# How to exclude ExtractField$Key for heartbeat topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a Debezium source connector that listen cdc of `Product` table that has `id` column.
When I start connector, everything is worked fine. But I saw that the event partition keys are like `{"id" : "1"}`. I didn't want the partition key in that format. I just want it `1`.

So I add below configuration to my connector and start again. Everything is working fine until I have looked to logs.

```
"transforms": "extractKeyfromStruct",
"transforms.extractKeyfromStruct.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"transforms.extractKeyfromStruct.field": "id",
```

There was a log like that:

```
Error encountered in task product-connector. Executing stage 'TRANSFORMATION' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key', where source record is = SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=product}, sourceOffset={transaction_id=null, lsn_proc=315208, lsn_commit=307208, lsn=98107208, txId=71105, ts_usec=1333040}} ConnectRecord{topic='product.debezium-heartbeat.product', kafkaPartition=0, key=Struct{serverName=product}, keySchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.common.ServerNameKey:STRUCT}, value=Struct{ts_ms=18682}, valueSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.common.Heartbeat:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}.   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter]
17
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown field: id
```

I realized that connector try to extract id field not only the Product table event but also the heartbeat event which has not id field and I don't need also.

So I need above three config but I want to exclude them for heartbeat event. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Filter` transfor like this:

```
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
transforms.filter.condition=!topic.endsWith('product.debezium-heartbeat.product')
```

More in the docs here https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html